# Assigning variables in loop(Python)

Tags: python, arrays, loops

So I have this dataframe Ttrain where the sex column has 2 unique values male and female. What I need to do is run a loop, where the unique values from a column will be extracted and assigned to unique variables. So for sex column, a[1]= male and a[2] = female should be the output. I'm trying the following code:

```
u=Ttrain.Sex.unique()
a=[]
for i in range(len(u)):
    a.append(i)=u[i]
    print (a(i))
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Please pardon my lack of knowledge because I've just started programming 2 weeks back. Any help/suggestion will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: a.append(u[i])?

Comment: Whether you are expecting any of these : `a.append(u[i])` or `a[i]=u[i]`

Comment: Why do you need `a` if you have `u`?

Comment: `a = list(u)` ?

Comment: I need to work further with each categories hence I need the 'a' part as well @Mad_Scientist

Comment: @Vikas, i tried the latter as well..not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call `a.append(i)`, it is the argument, `i`, that gets appended to the list. So when you are assigning `u[i]` afterwards you are attempting to assign it to the result of the function call, but that is not something you can assign a value to. So when you append: it's the argument inside the parenthesis that is added to the list `a`.

```
u=Ttrain.Sex.unique()
a=[]
for i in range(len(u)):
    a.append(i)=u[i]
    print (a(i))
```

Also, when you print `a(i)`, the syntax for indexing a list is `a[i]`, since the `call ()` operator will attempt to call the list, and since a list is just a container that makes no sense in this case.

Comment: Thnks for the info. Can you give me the correct syntax then?@Carl

Comment: For which part, the `append()` or something else? @Dipayan The append is `x.append(valueToAppendToList)`